# Saltstack send event to minions from master in python script

Tags: python, salt-stack

I'm trying to send an event from my salt master (Linux) to the minions (Windows) event bus.
On the master I can execute

```
salt 'MyMinion' event.fire '{"foo": "bar"}' 'custom/tag'
```

On the minion I have the listener script from the salt documentation

```
# Job on minion
import salt.utils.event

opts = salt.config.minion_config(salt.minion.DEFAULT_MINION_OPTS)
event = salt.utils.event.MinionEvent(opts)

for evdata in event.iter_events(match_type="regex", tag="custom/.*"):
    # do your processing here...
    ...
```

This works fine. As soon as the event is fired, I can process it on the minion.
What I'm trying to achieve now is to send the same event from the master to the minions but from a python script.
What I tried was the following:

```
from salt.modules.event import fire
payload = {"foo": "bar"}
tag = 'custom/tag'
fire(payload,tag)
```

This always returns false, and no event is send. I'm sure I'm missing something here but don't know where to go from there.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the script as below:

```
import salt.client
local = salt.client.LocalClient()

payload = '{"foo": "bar"}'
tag = 'custom/tag'
local.cmd('*', 'event.fire',[payload,tag])
```

As you noticed, I'm creating a local salt-master client which will take the default configuration (/etc/salt/master)

You can read more about [Salt's Python Client Api here](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/clients/index.html)